# Logstash Elasticsearch compression

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a working ELK stack and would like to enable index compression.

The official [store compression documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/store-compression-in-lucene-and-elasticsearch) tells me that I need to do it at index creation.

I couldn't find anything related to store compression or even index settings in the related [logstash output documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template)

Below is my logstash output configuration:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

And the created index settings:

```
{
  "filebeat-2016.04.28": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1461915752875",
        "uuid": "co8bvXI7RFKFwB7oJqs8cA",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "version": {
          "created": "2030199"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of logstash are you using?

Comment: Logstash 2.3, Elasticsearch 2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide your own index template file in order to enable index compression.

So you need to create your `filebeat-template.json` file like this. This file will be used by logstash when creating a new filebeat index.

```
{
  "template" : "filebeat-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index.codec" : "best_compression"
  }
}
```

Then your `elasticsearch` output should be modified like this:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    sniffing => true
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    template_name => "filebeat-template"
    template => "/path/to/filebeat-template.json"
  }
}
```

Then you can delete your existing `filebeat-2016.04.28` index and relaunch logstash. The latter will create an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) called `/_template/filebeat-template` which will kick in everytime ES needs to create a new index whose name starts with `filebeat-` and it will apply the settings (among which the store compression one) present in the template.

Comment: Oh I didn't knew about elasticsearch templates. Testing this right now thanks!